# Process Builder Error with Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api, process-builder

I set up a process to update the owner of a custom object (Program),

When Formula evaluates to true: [Program__c].OwnerId <>[Program__c].Franchise__c.OwnerId 
Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction? NO
Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record? NO

Immediate Action: for Object Program__c
Set Object Variable:
Field: Owner ID
Value: Program__c.Account__r.OwnerId

The Process works when Programs are updated through Salesforce, but when a Bulk API process ran I received this error message:

> Encountered unhandled fault when running process
>   Program_Owner_Update/301F000000006kW exception by user/organization:
>   00DA0000000IbPA/{4}
>
> UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS : 
>   (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK) Record rolled back because not all
>   records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header ---  for
>   SFDC record with ID :,
>
> caused by element : FlowRecordUpdate.myRule_1_A1
>
> caused by: UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS : 
>   (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK) Record rolled back because not all
>   records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header ---  for
>   SFDC record with ID : ,
>
> Salesforce Error ID: 572482331-21762 (-569115646)

Can the process builder be used with Bulk API updates?

Comment: Have you tried with `All Or None` turned off? Do any records go through?

Comment: I'm using a python script to run a csv through DemandTools. I don't know if DemandTools has an `All or None` option.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't see anywhere in the documentation that `All or None` is supported on the Bulk API.  It is suppose to work that way by default.

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that if Process Builder fails on any record, it currently causes the entire batch to rollback.

The [official workaround from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000230650&language=en_US) is to set the batch size to 1.  The claim this will only cause a minimal impact to sync times... I beg to differ.

In my cases I was getting `Unable to Lock Row` exceptions because the Flow was updating related records (and two flows tried to update the same one).  Turning off parrellel processing can help this, but no guaranteed you won't run into Row Lock issues due to users.

Answer (score 0):

Process builder will have to use APEX @InvocableMethod to support bulk API and do logic in the apex class .

Comment: Does this mean that the Process Builder can't be used on objects that are updated by the Bulk API?

Comment: looks like for now atleast .It can be but tie with apex .I mean handle the input to apex from process builder

Comment: Safe Harbor: Salesforce devs shared with me that 'bulkification' is on the immediate roadmap for Process Builder.