# Is Process builder a complete alternate for the triggers

Tags: process-builder, bulkification, trigggers

I need to do some analysis on process builder for taking a decision on config vs coding.

Saying that process builder is the alternate for the Triggers for updating the child records.

After creating some processes I noticed the following.

1) It can update the child records after meeting a condition on the parent record.

--> Here my observation is what if we need to update only specific child records, that means we are running out of options in this case we can not exert conditions at child record level.

--> So far I came across the couple of posts on bulk update or inserts issues with the process builder. for reference

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DhBlAAK.

[Process Builder Error with Bulk API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66601/process-builder-error-with-bulk-api/67210)

So here I would like to submit my analysis as process builder is not the complete alternate for the triggers since it has limitations on updating or inserting child records and also in doing the bulk updates/inserts. 
My question is I am I analysing the right way or missing some thing and if there is any thing more can i add to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process builder is not meant to be the complete alternative for triggers but it can eliminate some. I see it more as an eventual replacement for workflow. As far as the child records, in Summer 15 there is an update that deals with that, from the release notes [here](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_update_record_conditions.htm):

> Define Additional Conditions When Updating Records
>
> When you update records in your process, you can now filter the
>   records you’re updating using conditions.
>
> To add conditions in an Update Records action:
>
> Select the Updated records meet all conditions option.
>
> Set the conditions that you want to use to filter the updated records.
>
> Example
>
> Let’s say your process updates the status of a parent case when the
>   status of the child case is changed. You can now specify conditions
>   (2) so that, for example, you won’t update the parent case (1) if its
>   status is set to On Hold (3).

Comment: Yes `Process Builder` = `Workflow On Steroids`.

Answer (score 5):

One other thing to consider:

If you use triggers, you are forced to write testmethods and if you do a good job of this (lots of asserts, positive and negative tests, ...), you'll end up with a comprehensive set of regression tests

If you use Process Builder, this testing requirement has to be met in other ways:

- A browser automated testing tool (Selenium)
- Your own (possibly haphazard) UI testing before release
- Wait for users to complain something isn't working
- Apex testmethods that simulate the CRUD event and then assert expected results

Comment: Yeah testing is a major weakness. You *can* test it...but no one is going to go out of their way to do that.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  -- point and click and hope :-)

Comment: Rah Rah Clicks Not Code! I am in favor of that, but also wary of it I would also mention error handling is significantly less robust, though many don't know what they want in that area anyway.

Comment: @crop ,But if I create a process once and save it I can not edit it and If i have a to change my criteria I need to deactivate and create the entire process again, what if I am in a situation of trial and error, this increases my efforts right?

Comment: @suresh - you simply save as a new version and then edit; no need to recreate the process

Answer (score 1):

Trouble I had with process builder was:

1. Max 200 records per batch.
2. If you also have a trigger on the same object, this trigger would run per record basis. So if you had SOQL query there, effectively, the batch limit is 100.

Comment: In regards to your second point, is there some documentation for that?  It seems very limiting.  i.e. if it triggers some code that results in multiple SOQL queries, it drastically reduces the effective batch limit

Comment: Also implies that it should tear through `DML Operations`...

Comment: The issue was that process builder was updating the same triggered record.