# Trigger VS Process Automation

Tags: apex, trigger

To automate some Business process either i can go for 
Trigger/ Process Automation which include:- workflow, Approval Process, Process Builder, Visual Workflow.

Both Trigger and Process Automation help me to achieve this.
so My Question is:-
"when should i use Trigger and when to use Process Automation" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is that **you should use a Trigger when you cannot do what you want to do with the declarative features of Salesforce.** [Salesforce best practice states that one should leverage the declarative features of Salesforce first (#8).](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/apex-best-practices-15-apex-commandments.html)

Process Builder is improving with almost every release, and can be used with more and more complicated use cases. This [link](http://www.slideshare.net/ProQuestIT/process-builder-vs-trigger) provides very helpful scenarios where Process Builder would be preferable to Triggers.

That isn't to say that Process Builder is a 'silver bullet' - there are still considerations to take into account. As per this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78774/is-process-builder-a-complete-alternate-for-the-triggers), I think the most compelling consideration is that from @cropredy:

> If you use triggers, you are forced to write testmethods and if you do
>   a good job of this (lots of asserts, positive and negative tests,
>   ...), you'll end up with a comprehensive set of regression tests
>
> If you use Process Builder, this testing requirement has to be met in
>   other ways:
>
> 1. A browser automated testing tool (Selenium)
> 2. Your own (possibly haphazard) UI testing before release
> 3. Wait for users to complain something isn't working
> 4. Apex testmethods that simulate the CRUD event and then assert
>      expected results

Slightly unrelated to your question but quite interesting is that the gap in time investment between Flow and relatively simple Apex triggers isn't that much, so as per the [Apex Academy video tutorial series on Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/apex-absolute-beginner-guide-coding-salesforce), it *may* be more beneficial and less 'technical debt' to use triggers in that particular use case.

Answer (score 5):

As a good practice you should always try to use formulas, workflows or processes over a Trigger as it is easier to maintain and update. However in some cases the  business process might be too complex for the options mentioned above so you would need to use a trigger in this case.

Consider the following scenarios 1): you need to assign ownership to a custom object based on some criteria. You can achieve this with with both triggers and process builder but the process would require a new process each time a change is require so depending on the complexity level it could become very hard to administer all the rules in the process builder.

Overall the main issues with process builder are :

- **editing** ( you cannot edit a process once is activated)
- **autosave** ( you can't cancel out of a process if you made unwanted changes),
- **debugging** (the UI doesn't allow the admin to see the
  created_date , id or created_by of the process),
- **validation** (
  processes don t trigger validation rules)
- **deletion** ( you need
  to wait 12 h after making a process inactive to delete it)  etc.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question basically depends on the requirement that you have worked on. The usage of Trigger or Process Automation Tools will vary according to the simple and complex scenarios.

If you take a visual workflow, you can automate the process with simple steps and can do with heavy customization. Choosing a Trigger or Process Automation Tool is based on your capacity of your requirement.

Even if the Process Automation Tools are very easy to develop the hard processings, they too have their own drawbacks. So, before you choose where to develop, you need to know the full functionalities of all according to your needs.

Hope this might helps...

Answer (score 0):

When you have a very complex use case that should handle Insert,Delete,Update on parent and child and validation then trigger should be used.

if have a simple use case and depend on single object and does not depend on multiple object Process automation is the best choice.