# How to avoid the bulk flow issue in the Process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have created a process builder flow, but if any single record is not valid , my entire flow is getting failed, with the below error message,
its showing the request is using " All or none header". Can you plz advise me , if we can deactivate the All or none process, i want that it should run for the valid records only , avoiding the invalid ones. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you Going to load data from any third party tool ?

Comment: Hello Dev, No. It was showing similar kind of errors while i use to load from data loader, which i removed by making the batch size as 1, But here its a PB flow written related to the account and Quote object. Account address is migrating to Quote aaddress fields, But if certain account address is blank ( address is not mandatory in acc) , then while creating a Quote its showing PB flow error mentioned as above.

Comment: Have you gone through this question : [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66601/process-builder-error-with-bulk-api) i guess this is something useful information to your problem

Comment: This is may be due to validation rule/required field missing/any trigger related to this object. Do you have anything like this

Comment: Hi reshma, No the address fields are not mandataory in the account. and as i can checked no validation rules etc been linked. But in PB during "define criteria" i had put " No criteri-just update the action".

Comment: Hi Dev, i went through the link, but i cant able to figure out any solutions mentioned.

Comment: Generally, if address in account is blank, the Quote adresss should also be blank, isnt it?